# GUI in python code

Tags: python, tkinter

Im a beginner at programming and i need some help, i need to put this python(3.5.3) code in a GUI. I've already read a lot of tkinter tutorials but none of these helped me.
I need to all the inputs and the print to appear on the screen.
Here's the code:

```
entrada_salario = float(input("Qual o seu  salário mensal? "))

entrada_horas = int(input("Quantas horas você trabalha por dia?"))

entrada_dias = int(input("Quantos dias por semana você trabalha?"))

horas_trabalhadas = ( entrada_horas * entrada_dias ) * 4

valor_hora = entrada_salario / horas_trabalhadas

custo_cem = 100 / valor_hora

print("Você trabalha" , horas_trabalhadas, "h por mês, recebe R$" , valor_hora,"por hora e seu custo 100 é de %.2f" %custo_cem)
```

Comment: You need to actually explain what you're trying to do. "i need to put this python code in a GUI" is painfully vague. To accomplish what goal? What should the GUI even do? What have you tried already?

Comment: [thenewboston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJB1Ek2Ko_Y&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBwibXFtPtflztSNPGuIB_d) tutorial was where I got started, you can put your code into tkinter if you study and watch this or a couple of other tutorials.

Comment: So from what I can see is you have some math going on and you are printing some results out to the consol. By your statement you want the `code in a GUI` and I can only assume this means you want some entry boxes where a user can put in numbers and then have some kind of submit button and have the results display on the screen.

Comment: There's no question in your question. What do you need help with? Start by creating a tkinter program based on what you leaned from a tutorial, and then show us where you're getting stuck.

Comment: The main problem is: i don't know how to put the inputs and the print on the GUI

Comment: @GustavoSerafim: You don't put prints and inputs into a GUI. You manipulate widgets to get your desired results. Take a look at my answer where I give a brief discretion of each element of the GUI you need to make the kind of program you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from what I can see you just don't understand the basics of a tkinter or any GUI for that matter. That being said you really should build some programs from tutorials so you can get the grasp of GUI's.

What you want to do is very simple with even the very basics of tkinter.

Here is how you would go about doing this with a simple GUI.

```
#import Tkinter as tk # this import is for Python 2.x
import tkinter as tk # this import is for Python 3.x

root = tk.Tk() # this is used to define the tkinter wondow

# each label below is for the user to know what to place in each entry box
label1 = tk.Label(root, text = "Qual o seu  salário mensal? ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Quantas horas você trabalha por dia?").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
label3 = tk.Label(root, text = "Quantos dias por semana você trabalha?").grid(row = 2, column = 0)

# each entry box configured to be places next to each label. Simple stuff
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry3 = tk.Entry(root)
entry3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

# this tkinter text box is where we will print out results
text_box = tk.Text(root, height = 2, width = 100)
text_box.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

def do_math(): #this function will only work if every entry has a number in it
# I did not spend the time to write in any error checking as this is just an example of what to do.

    # we can get the values of each entry box with .get()
    # make sure we are working with an integer with the int() function.
    horas_trabalhadas = (int(entry2.get()) * int(entry3.get())) * 4
    valor_hora = int(entry1.get()) / horas_trabalhadas
    custo_cem = 100 / valor_hora
    results = "Você trabalha" , horas_trabalhadas, "h por mês, recebe R$" , valor_hora,"por hora e seu custo 100 é de %.2f" %custo_cem

    # this is the command to print results to the text box.
    text_box.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
    text_box.insert("end-1c", results)
    text_box.see("end-1c")

# this button is configured to call the do_math(): function when it is pressed
submit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = do_math).grid(row = 3)

root.mainloop() # required at then end of your tkinter program
```

Comment: This is what i need, thank you very much.